# A unique number sequence in main task and subtask query

Tags: sql-server

In both main tasks and subtasks, I would like to add a column TaskId with a unique number starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 also the subtask TaskId should be right after it is main task.

Suppose I have five main tasks, of which the first has three subtasks, the second two subtasks, and the third, fourth, and fifth none.
Therefore, the sequence should be as follows:

The first main task gets 1 and 2,3,4 for its subtasks, the second main task gets 5 and its subtasks 6,7, and the third main task gets 8, the fourth gets 9, the fifth gets 10.

```
;WITH ProjectTasks AS 
(
    -- Main tasks query
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(i.ProjectN,' ',c.Name,' ',FORMAT(i.Weight, 'N2'),' Kg',' -', 
        CASE 
            WHEN FKPaint = 2 THEN 'Peinture' 
            WHEN FKGalva = 3 THEN 'Galvanisation' 
            WHEN FKNoir = 4 THEN 'Noir' 
            ELSE '' 
        END) AS TaskName,
        i.DateProject AS StartDate, 
        i.DateDelivery AS EndDate, 
        i.id AS ProjectId
        --Add new column TaskId
    FROM 
        ProjectInfo i
    INNER JOIN 
        Customer c ON i.FK_Customer = c.ID
    WHERE  
        i.DateDelivery >= '07-01-2023'
),
SubTasks AS 
(
    -- Subtasks query
    SELECT 
        pc.Title AS TaskName,
        p.StartDate, p.EndDate,
        p.MetallicConstructionId 
        --Add new column TaskId
    FROM 
        MetallicConstructionPlanning p
    INNER JOIN 
        PlanningCategory pc ON p.PlanningCategoryId = pc.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        ProjectInfo i ON p.MetallicConstructionId = i.id
) 
SELECT 
    pt.*, 
    st.TaskName, 
    st.StartDate, st.EndDate
    --st.TaskId
FROM 
    ProjectTasks pt
LEFT JOIN 
    SubTasks st ON pt.ProjectId = st.MetallicConstructionId
```

I try to use `ROW_NUMBER()` but without any success

Thanks in advance
**Update**
I am looking for Tasks with related subtasks in order to use them in a Syncfusion Blazor Gantt chart.
This is my C# code

```
public static class ProjectMetallicConstructionEndpoints
{
    public static void MapProjectMetallicConstructionEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.MapGet("projectchinfo", async (SqlConnectionFactory sqlConnectionFactory) =>
        {
            using var connection = sqlConnectionFactory.Create();
            try
            {
                var lookup = new Dictionary<int, ProjectMetallicConstructionGanttDto>();

                var result = await connection.QueryAsync<ProjectMetallicConstructionGanttDto, ProjectMetallicConstructionGanttDto, ProjectMetallicConstructionGanttDto>(
                    "ProjectMetallicConstructionGanttDto",
                    (gantt, details) =>
                    {

                        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(gantt.TaskId, out ProjectMetallicConstructionGanttDto ganttEntry))
                        {
                            lookup.Add(gantt.TaskId, ganttEntry = gantt);
                        }

                        ganttEntry.SubTasks ??= [];

                        if (details != null)
                            ganttEntry.SubTasks.Add(details);

                        return ganttEntry;
                    },
                    splitOn: "TaskId",
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
                );

                var projectList = lookup.Values.ToList();
                return projectList.Count != 0 ? Results.Ok(projectList) : Results.NotFound("No data found.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception here
                return Results.Problem($"An error occurred while fetching data.\n {ex.Message}");
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectInfo](
    [id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [FK_Customer] [int] NULL) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MetallicConstructionPlanning](
    [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MetallicConstructionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PlanningCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL
) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetallicConstructionPlanning]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MetallicConstructionPlanning_ProjectInfo] FOREIGN KEY([MetallicConstructionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProjectInfo] ([id])
```

And this is how the data should be

| TaskName | StartDate | EndDate | ProjectId | MainTaskId | TaskName | StartDate | EndDate | SubTaskId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 589.30 Kg -Peinture | 2023-11-15 | 2024-02-06 | 2287 | 1 | Etude | 2023-11-16 | 2023-11-27 | 2 |
| Project1 589.30 Kg -Peinture | 2023-11-15 | 2024-02-06 | 2287 | 1 | Réalisation | 2023-11-28 | 2023-12-07 | 3 |
| Project2 6,655.50 Kg -Galvanisation | 2023-11-19 | 2023-12-10 | 2288 | 4 | Etude | 2023-11-19 | 2023-11-21 | 5 |
| Project2 6,655.50 Kg -Galvanisation | 2023-11-19 | 2023-12-10 | 2288 | 4 | Réalisation | 2023-11-22 | 2023-12-10 | 6 |
| Project3 28.40 Kg -Noir | 2023-11-20 | 2023-11-23 | 2289 | 7 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: It sounds like you do need ROW_NUMBER() but with one of the options like partition and/or order by.  Look into the different options for ROW_NUMBER and you should be able to find one that does what you are looking for.

Comment: Try --Add new column TaskId ``row_number()over(order by i.id,p.StartDate,pc.Title) TaskId``

Comment: if you an provide sample data and DDL for the tables that will help us to help you

Comment: Please always include sample data and desired results for that sample data; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: I have updated my question. My apologies, the table in preview shows correctly

Answer (score 0):

For the main task you can use: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS TaskId`.
For your subtasks you'd have to find a logical way using `ROW_NUMBER()` again to get the values based on your main task.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign sequence numbers by (1) constructing a `UNION` of just the tasks plus the tasks and subtasks combined, (2) applying an appropriate order that places the subtasks immediately after the tasks, and (3) then using `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign sequence numbers.

That would then be fed into a query that `LEFT JOIN`s tasks and subtasks and performs two separate joins back to the generated sequence numbers - one matching just the task ID (and subtask ID = NULL), and the second matching just the subtask ID.

Using a simplified schema, t overall query would be something like:

```
WITH CTE_NumberedTaskSubtasks AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(ORDER BY U.TaskStart, U.TaskId, U.SubTaskStart, U.SubTaskId)
            AS Seq,
        U.TaskId,
        U.SubTaskId
    FROM (
        SELECT
            T.TaskId, T.TaskStart,
            S.SubTaskId, S.SubTaskStart
        FROM Task T
        JOIN SubTask S ON S.TaskId = T.TaskId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            T.TaskId, T.TaskStart,
            NULL, NULL
        FROM Task T
    ) U
)
SELECT
    N1.Seq AS TaskSeq,
    T.*,
    N2.Seq AS SubTaskSeq,
    S.*
FROM Task T
JOIN CTE_NumberedTaskSubtasks N1
    ON N1.TaskId = T.TaskId
    AND N1.SubTaskId IS NULL -- Just the main task number
LEFT JOIN SubTask S ON S.TaskId = T.TaskId
LEFT JOIN CTE_NumberedTaskSubtasks N2
    ON N2.SubTaskId = S.SubTaskId
ORDER BY
    N1.Seq,
    N2.Seq
```

You could also wrap the task + sequence and subtask + sequence joins up into additional CTEs, if you find that more convenient or readable.

```
-- Alternate query using additional CTEs
WITH CTE_NumberedTaskSubtasks AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(ORDER BY U.TaskStart, U.TaskId, U.SubTaskStart, U.SubTaskId)
            AS Seq,
        U.TaskId,
        U.SubTaskId
    FROM (
        SELECT
            T.TaskId, T.TaskStart,
            S.SubTaskId, S.SubTaskStart
        FROM Task T
        JOIN SubTask S ON S.TaskId = T.TaskId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            T.TaskId, T.TaskStart,
            NULL, NULL
        FROM Task T
    ) U
),
CTE_Task AS (
    SELECT N.Seq AS TaskSeq, T.*
    FROM Task T
    JOIN CTE_NumberedTaskSubtasks N
        ON N.TaskId = T.TaskId
        AND N.SubTaskId IS NULL -- Just the main task number
),
CTE_SubTask AS (
    SELECT N.Seq AS SubTaskSeq, S.*
    FROM SubTask S
    JOIN N.SubTaskId = S.SubTaskId
        ON N.SubTaskId = S.SubTaskId
)
SELECT
    T.*,
    S.*
FROM CTE_Task T
LEFT JOIN CTE_SubTask S ON S.TaskId = T.TaskId
ORDER BY
    T.TaskSeq,
    S.SubTaskSeq
```

The assigned sequence numbers would be like the following:

| Seq | TaskId | SubTaskId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | *null* |
| 2 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 1 | 12 |
| 4 | 1 | 13 |
| 5 | 2 | *null* |
| 6 | 2 | 21 |
| 7 | 2 | 22 |
| 8 | 3 | *null* |
| 9 | 4 | *null* |
| 10 | 5 | *null* |

The final results would be like:

| Task Seq | Task Id | Task Name | Task Start | SubTask Seq | SubTask Id | Task Id | SubTask Name | SubTask Start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2024-03-07 08:00 | 2 | 11 | 1 | A1 | 2024-03-07 09:30 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2024-03-07 08:00 | 3 | 12 | 1 | A2 | 2024-03-07 10:30 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2024-03-07 08:00 | 4 | 13 | 1 | A3 | 2024-03-07 11:30 |
| 5 | 2 | B | 2024-03-07 09:00 | 6 | 21 | 2 | B1 | 2024-03-07 09:15 |
| 5 | 2 | B | 2024-03-07 09:00 | 7 | 22 | 2 | B2 | 2024-03-07 09:45 |
| 8 | 3 | C | 2024-03-07 10:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 9 | 4 | D | 2024-03-07 11:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 10 | 5 | E | 2024-03-07 12:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X7ZrNgZN) for a demo.

Comment: I appreciate your hard work very much 
However, TaskId is not a real column; it is just a sequence number holder.
I am looking for Tasks with related subtasks in order to use them in a Syncfusion Blazor Gantt chart.
I have updated my question. Please take a look

Comment: My intent was to show the technique and demonstrate it using the simplified data from the first few lines of your description. Since you have not provided and real sample *source* data for your full scenario, I can't do much more. I'll leave it to you to adapt this technique to your live environment.